# Inner loop behaving strange in R

Tags: r, range, nested-loops

```
for (i in range(1:4)) {
    for (j in range(1:4)) {
        print ("Processing...")
    }
}
```

Simple, plain nested loop resulting in this output:

```
[1] "Processing..."
[1] "Processing..."
[1] "Processing..."
[1] "Processing..."
```

This is making me zero sense. Actual program is a bit complex, I just wanted to know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "`range` returns a vector containing the minimum and maximum of all the given arguments", so you're only actually iterating twice per loop. Instead just use `for (i in 1:4)`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the sequence by not using `range`. I think you may be confusing it with the Python function. 
From the help page:

> ‘range’ returns a vector containing the minimum and maximum of all
>        the given arguments.

So what is happening is that you're taking the sequences and returning the min and max values (1 and 4 for each respectively) rather than enumerating.

Try this:

```
for (i in 1:4) {
    for (j in 1:4) {
        print ("Processing...")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I need some coffee :-x